Movie where guy and girl are in town with exit routes that all lead back to town
I'm looking for a film I saw on IFC 8-10 years ago. I don't remember a whole lot about it other than this guy and girl are in this small town in what seemed to be the American midwest, and they're trying to leave and every time they try, they end up going in a circle even though they're not aware of it until they reach an identifying landmark. It was like a Bermuda triangle but it was a small, dusty town.
I think at one point they ran out of gas or something and one of them went for help and after a long time the other went after them.
I don't think either of the actors were well known, there wasn't many characters other than a few odd shopkeepers and things like that. And they were odd, like strange.
I think it would be considered a "Thriller" as I don't remember anything particularly scary about it, but it was weirder than a drama.

Kind of reminds me of the episode of Nightmares and Dreamscapes called "Crouch End" although I don't remember one of them leaving for help.

May be Dark Country

This same trope happens towards the end of "In the Mouth of Madness", starring Sam Neill. However, it's at night and there is a scary mob trying to kill (??) the 2 people in the car. And the movie is definitely scary!

I checked on the Crouch End episode, I don't think that's it as it took place in London and this one seemed to be in the American midwest. Dark Country seemed like it might be it but after viewing the trailer, I don't believe that's it.

I don't think Sam Neill was in this one.

Pleasantville had this feature, i.e. where people couldn't leave town because they would end up "looping back" into town. It took place in a (fictional) Iowa suburb in the 1950s.

Sounds like "Stopover in a Quiet Town" episode of The Twilight Zone.

They hear a train whistle and, thinking they have finally found a way out of the town, rush to the train station and board the empty train. As the train leaves the station (revealed to be in "Centerville"), they begin a light-hearted conversation, vastly relieved. However, when the train soon comes to a stop again in Centerville, they realize it has only gone in a circle, and they are back where they started.


Welcome! To help improve your answer, could you please point out what parts of this episode match up with the description in the question?

Could it be Persons Unknown?  There was a 13 episode mini-series broadcast on NBC in 2010:

Seven strangers disappear without a trace and wake up together in a hotel room.  The suspense is in finding out why they were taken -- and by whom. (Netflix synopsis)
Several strangers awaken and find themselves imprisoned inside a small ghost town. They quickly search for answers and along the way start to question each other's motives. (IMDB synopsis)

There was apparently also a 1996 film but with an related plot.

IMDB entry
Wikipedia entry
Netflix entry


I don't think so as it was just centered around this one couple

I don't think this is it because this film was just about the one couple. Not much of a cast was in it other than the couple and a few odd store keepers and such
